How to get retrieve only custom slide tags in OpenXML?
I was using the OpenXML library in C# and trying to get the user defined tags attached to a specific slide.
Here's how I initially went about it:
//  SlidePart slidePart;
var slideTags = slidePart.UserDefinedTagsParts.SelectMany(tp => tp.TagList.Elements<Tag>());

However, this does not only return the custom tags attached to the slide, but also all of the tags attached to the shapes inside the slide.
I eventually found a solution and will post an answer.

The trick is to make use of relationship IDs. (I'm used to Office Interop so OpenXML is such a headache)
// Get the slide-specific tag relationship ID
var slideSpecificTagsId = slidePart.Slide
                                   .Descendants<CustomerDataList>()
                                   .SingleOrDefault(cdl => cdl.Parent.GetType() == typeof(CommonSlideData))?
                                   .Descendants<CustomerDataTags>()
                                   .SingleOrDefault()
                                   .Id;

// use that relationship ID to get to retrieve only that specific part
var slideSpecificTags = slideSpecificTagsId != null
                        ? ((UserDefinedTagsPart)slidePart.GetPartById(slideSpecificTagsId))
                                                         .TagList
                                                         .Elements<Tag>()
                                                         .ToList()
                        : null;

